# JQuery Datpicker stacks month and year

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I selected the options to have a month and year drop down menus but instead of putting them side by side like the demo it stacks them one on top of the other. How do I change it so they are side by side?  Also my calendar is neither the same size or has the same font as the demo and to get it close I had to follow what others said as well.

```
$(function() {
        $( "#mydate" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
});
```

Comment: Please post your html and css code.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the CSS configured on jQuery UI for the  *ui-widget* class has *font-size:1.1em*. The "em" is a scalable unit.
You can rewrite that css property and use an fixed-size unit if you want:

```
.ui-widget{
     font-size:11px;
 }
```